# Alternative to using order by rand ()?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently i have query using order by rand() to get 1000 different rows and not increment.

Any idea how to optimize this query that returns 1000 random results and not increment, such as this:

```
select * 
 from table1 
 where not exists
        ( select id 
            from table2 
           where id = table1.id) 
   and prize_list_id = 100 
   and prize_group_id  in (109,111,113,119,120,127,129) 
 order 
    by rand() limit 1000;
```

Comment: whats the format of **id**, is it an integer ?

Comment: define "optimize".

Comment: No, not really. That looks pretty optimal. A composite index on prize_list_id and prize_group_id might be useful.

Comment: yes it is data type of id is integer

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. i did composite index on prize_list_id and prize_group_id.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you don't know how many rows will be returned, so that needs to be calculated.

The idea is the following:

- Calculate the number of rows being returned.
- Use `rand()` in a `WHERE` clause to whittle down the set to a reasonable number.
- Use `order by rand()` for the final randomness.

This looks like:

```
select t.*
from (select t1.*, (@cnt := @cnt + 1) as seqnum,
             rand() as rnd
      from table1 t1 cross join
           (select @cnt := 0) params
      where not exists (select id 
                        from table2 
                        where id = table1.id
                       ) and
            prize_list_id = 100 and
            prize_group_id in (109, 111, 113, 119, 120, 127, 129) 
     ) t
where rnd < 2000 / @cnt
order by rnd
limit 1000
```

The `where` should choose somewhere around 2000 rows, which is a safe number to be sure you have at least 1000 (actually, you can probably use a smaller number like 1200).  The `order by` is then on a smaller subset and should be faster.

I don't think that `rand()` is a particularly expensive function, but this pre-calculates a value for each row so it is only called once for each row in the subquery.